# How to configure a AWS ELB with https listener to work with docker containers running http only web servers?

Tags: amazon-elb

This is my setup so far:

Application Load Balancer and its listener

[image]

The purpose is to enable https on the load balancer's end. Then it will forward traffic to the target group which is a collection of docker containers.

At the moment the web servers running in the docker containers can only handle http traffic.

So it is how I define the target group:

[image]

But apparently it fails the health check:

[image]

My question is:

- Is it possible at all to have a ssl-enabled loadbalancer to forward request in http to the docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can restate my requirement in my question as:

> I want https traffic to terminate at the load balancer and then
>   forward to my docker containers in http.

To achieve this, I need to

**1)** Enable a https listener in the application load balancer

[image]

**2)** Make sure it will talk to the target group with http protocol

[image]

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

There is a example in Docker documentation about this subject [How can I configure my load balancer to support SSL/TLS traffic?](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/load-balancer/#examples)